# Finding the top level directory, shortening path PHP

Tags: php, path

I have this which is probably a roundabout way of finding the path:

```
<?php require_once $parent_dir = dirname(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))).'/myFile.php'; ?>
```

It works, but is there a cleaner way of writing it?

My site has a subdomain. Here's where myFile.php is located:

http://sub.mydomain.com/dir/

Comment: Do you mean top-level directory?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Changing subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes `getcwd` can be useful:

```
require_once getcwd() . '/../../myFile.php' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but maybe `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but perhaps something like this will shorten it for you:

```
$pathArr = explode("/", __DIR__);
var_dump($pathArr);
// previous was for debugging to see what gets put where, remove this once you sort it out.

// list($level1, $level2, ...) = explode("/", __FILE__);
```

Comment: Hey! Not sure this is what OP was looking for but it's definitely what I was looking for! Needed to find "hello" from `/hello/this/is/a/long/path/file.php` and explode seem to be one of the short ways to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP 5.3 (or above), you can use `__DIR__`:

```
$parent_dir = __DIR__.'/../myFile.php';
```

Your example seems to go a couple levels further up, so you can add to that:

```
$parent_dir = __DIR__.'/../../myFile.php';
```

`__DIR__` is a magic constant that evaluates to the directory the file that calls it is located.

And as highlighted in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103394/818057), if you're after the root, `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` will give you the path as defined in your server (eg. Apache) config.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after more than 10 years, it may still help someone else.

If you need to find the top-level directory from whatever path, you can do it with one single line of code:

```
$top_level_dirname = dirname( $path,substr_count( $path,'/' ) );
```

The function dirname accepts as a second argument (not required, and 1 as default) the number of parent directories to go up.
So, if you set that argument to the number of occurrences of "/", you will go up to the top.

Example:

```
$path = '/htdocs/public';

echo dirname( $path,substr_count( $path,'/' ); // will echo 'htdocs'

$path = '/htdocs/public/other_name';

echo dirname( $path,substr_count( $path,'/' ); // will still echo 'htdocs'
```